# issue with ImageEffect; EdgeStylization

Tags: image-processing, image

I have a issue with ImageEffect/EdgeStylization. After importing a .jpg-file like

```
test = Import["C:\\........\\DSCN0018_v1.jpg"]
```

The result is:

[image]

Then I take a smaller part of the picture and do the ImageEffect

```
    test1 = ImageTake[test, {1200, 5000}, {1200, 3000}]; 
test2 = ImageEffect[test1, {"EdgeStylization", 30}]
```

Normaly I don't have any problems and everything works fine. But sometimes I get strange colorised stripes like this image:

[image]

What can be the reason and what is a solution for this issue?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the resolution. If I lower the resolution it works fine!